# Jaxb wildcard umarshalling marshalling

Tags: java, jaxb

first of all sorry for my poor english. I would like to unmarshal and than marshal the following classes.

```
@XmlSeeAlso({B1.class, C1.class})
public abstract class A1 implements Serializable {

private String parameterName;

  public A1 () {
  }


  public A1 (String parameterName) {
      this.parameterName = parameterName;
  }

  public String getParameterName() {
      return parameterName;
  }
}
```

SubClasses

```
public class B1 extends A1{
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private Collection dataSource = new ArrayList();

public B1 () {

}


@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public B1 (String parameterName, Collection dataSource) {
    super(parameterName);
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}


@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public B1 (Collection dataSource) {
    super("B");
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public Collection getDataSource() {
    return dataSource;
}
```

AND

```
public class C1 extends A1 {

private String imagePath;


public C1() {

}

protected C1(String parameterName) {
    super(parameterName);
}


public C1 (String parameterName, String imagePath) {
    super(parameterName);
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
}

public String getImagePath() {
    return imagePath;
}
```

Subclasses are in a Collection

```
List<? extends A1>
```

After unmarshaling and marshalling fieds will be null (for example: parameterName). The application doesn't throw any exception.

Comment: Show us the xml you are trying to unmarshall, please.